# Need Help regarding Page Breaks while generating DOC from PHP

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I'm trying to generate a doc file wrapping it through HTML codes in PHP using headers method. The method is working fine and I'm getting a proper docx file. However there are no page breaks in the docx file. No matter how long the text is it goes in a single page.
Here is the sample code..

```
&lt;?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=demo.doc");
echo "&lt;html>";
echo "&lt;meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset= Windows-1251\">";
echo "&lt;body>";
echo "<b>Random Text</b>";
echo "&lt;/body>";
echo "&lt;/html>";
?>
```

before posting this question I also tried google and came up that by adding below code many peoples solved the similar issue.

```
echo "&lt;br style='mso-special-character:line-break; pageBreakBefore:auto'>";
```

However this solution is not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open word
2. Create a document with a page break
3. Open docx in your favorite zip file program
4. Find content

Here's what I got using LibreOffice Writer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="style0"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr></w:rPr>
                <w:t>Before page break</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="style0"/>
                <w:pageBreakBefore/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr></w:rPr>
                <w:t>After</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr>
            <w:type w:val="nextPage"/>
            <w:pgSz w:h="15840" w:w="12240"/>
            <w:pgMar w:bottom="1134" w:footer="0" w:gutter="0" w:header="0" w:left="1134" w:right="1134" w:top="1134"/>
            <w:pgNumType w:fmt="decimal"/>
            <w:formProt w:val="false"/>
            <w:textDirection w:val="lrTb"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, sounds really cool.
but can you specify any "zip file program" for reading the content of docx file ?

Comment: [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [tugzip](http://www.tugzip.com/) will open up a docx. Or you can rename it to .zip and open it with the built in windows zip handler. Once you open it, you'll find the contents of your document in word/document.xml

Comment: Alright, I got it. It looks like they're using a tag <w:lastRenderedPageBreak/> for page break. Can you tell me how can I implement it in my PHP code which I demonstrated above.

Answer (score 1):

You just add a style to an HTML element wherever page break required.

```
<h2 style="page-break-before: always;">Next Page</h2>
```

This header will be displayed in a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question but this is what I am using and it works perfectly fine.

Docx XML uses this to break the pages

```xml
<w:br w:type="page"/>
```

Just use this after wherever you want a page break.

More info on pagebreak [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/12e84734-b7c9-4b7b-9dbc-d8730e779b57/determine-the-page-breaks-in-open-xml-document-for-docx-file?forum=oxmlsdk).